# How to PAN (alter the sound balance) the stereo channel of an flv file

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I want to be able to PAN the stereo channel of an flv file.
Ostensibly so that I can play one of 2 languages (right channel or left channel) when the flv is being played.
I have "played" with sound mixer and cannot get this to work with the flv.

Can I use soundMixer with videoPlayer and if so, can anyone correct my (below) code?

TIA,
    Phil.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            protected function myVideo():void
            {               
                var soundMixer:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
                soundMixer.pan = 1;
                myVid.soundTransform = soundMixer;

                myVid.play();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:Button  id="playVideo" label="Video"  click="myVideo()"/>

        <s:VideoPlayer id="myVid" 
                       source="assets/caroLang.flv"
                       volume="1.0"
                       width="50%" height="50%"
                       autoPlay="false"
                       autoDisplayFirstFrame="true"
                       scaleMode="letterbox"
                       />
    </s:VGroup>
</s:View>
```

Comment: Have a look at `soundTransform`.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to change tack and use multiple mp3 files (one for each language) with a video playing, which has no audio.

I am testing the selectLang variable and playing different mp3 files depending upon the value.

Start the process by clicking the video button, them you can stop, pause or use the scrubber bar to move the video and mp3 to the appropriate synced position.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView"
    creationComplete="view1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.core.SoundAsset;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        import spark.components.mediaClasses.ScrubBar;

        import org.osmf.events.MediaPlayerStateChangeEvent;
        import org.osmf.events.TimeEvent;
        import org.osmf.traits.PlayState;

        private var seletedLang:String = "EN";

        public var loadedFile:File;
        public var channel:SoundChannel;
        public var songEN:SoundAsset;   
        public var songPT:SoundAsset;           
        private var currentVidTime:Number = 0;


        protected functio view1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            songEN = new SoundAsset();
            songEN.load(new URLRequest("assets/caro.mp3"));

            songPT = new SoundAsset();
            songPT.load(new URLRequest("assets/caro.mp3"));

            myVid.addEventListener(TimeEvent.CURRENT_TIME_CHANGE, scrubBarChange);
        }

        protected function scrubBarChange(event:TimeEvent):void
        {
            currentVidTime = event.time;
        }

        protected function myVideo():void
        {                                   
            if(seletedLang == "EN")
            {
                channel = songEN.play(currentVidTime*1000);
            }
            else
            {
                channel = songPT.play(currentVidTime*1000);
            }

            myVid.play();

        }

        protected function myVid_mediaPlayerStateChangeHandler(event:MediaPlayerStateChangeEvent):void
        {
            trace(event.state);

            if(event.state == "playing")
            {
                if(seletedLang == "EN")
                {
                    trace("****  " + currentVidTime);
                    if ( channel != null ) channel = songEN.play(currentVidTime*1000);
                }
                else if (seletedLang == "PT")
                {
                    if ( channel != null ) channel = songPT.play(currentVidTime*1000);
                }
            }
            else if(event.state == "paused")
            {

                if ( channel != null ) SoundMixer.stopAll();
            }
        }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:Button  id="playVideo" label="Video"  click="myVideo()"/>

    <s:VideoPlayer id="myVid" 
                   source="assets/caroMute.flv"
                   volume="0.0"
                   width="50%" height="50%"
                   autoPlay="false"
                   autoDisplayFirstFrame="true"
                   scaleMode="letterbox"
                   mediaPlayerStateChange="myVid_mediaPlayerStateChangeHandler(event)"
                   />
</s:VGroup>
 </s:View>
```